# ¿Porque no me actualiza los cambios hecho en react?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-blade

Cuando hago `php artisan serve` todo bien me muestra el componente de prueba, pero cuando hago un cambio a ese componente , luego actualizo la página sigue mostrando lo mismo o sea la página de ejemplo, me gustaría saber que debo hacer para que actualice.

Example.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

 export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        /*
        PLANTILLA DE LOGGING -------------------
        */ 

          <div>
              <h1>HOLAAA MUNDODDDD</h1>
          </div>

       //----------------



      );
   }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>lara-react</title>
   <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >



 </head>
 <body>
   <div id='example'></div>

   <script type = "text/javascript" src="/js/app.js" ></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: Este es el ejmplo principal pero si hago cambios no actualiza]

Comment: Si aun asi no funciona, prueba con borrar el cache directemente desde tu navegador. o en su caso aplicar este comando en la terminal de tu proyecto: **php artisan route:clear**

Answer (score 2):

Te faltara compilarlo con webpack de nuevo, ejecuta el comando :

> npm run dev

o

> npm run watch

para actualizar a cada cambio en el js.